# How to increase the update download speed?

Tags: update-manager, download-speed

After installing Ubuntu 11.10 , I opened the Update Manager.
I found that the average download speed for updates is about 12 Kb/sec.
But I used to download with 64 Kb/sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apt-fast.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-fast upgrade
```

To install the latest updates available. You'll feel the speed difference.

Answer (score 3):

Those are terribly slow speeds. Assuming you have a broadband connection, you should try changing the download server. Try a few close to you.

Open Update Manager and click on the 'Settings' button at the bottom left. Click the 'Ubuntu Software' tab and change servers. I don't know what kind of connection you have but I typically see downloads max out my connection within a few seconds.

[image: download server change]

Comment: Many of the server don't have the latest packages.